# How to use the comparison test for this integral?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

$$\int_{π}^{∞} \frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{x} + \sin(x)} dx .$$

Need to prove the integral diverges. Tried to use all the different techniques but to no avail.

Comment: The integral seems convergent to me: the series for the comparison is $\sum_n (-1)^n/\sqrt{n}$

Comment: @DiegoG7 What are you talking about?

Comment: Ok, maybe it diverges!

Comment: My first comment overlooked an important detail, is wrong! See my Answer

Answer (score 1):

Using the Taylor expansion $1/(1+\varepsilon)=1-\varepsilon+O(\varepsilon^2) $, 
$$
\frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{x} + \sin(x)}=\frac{\sin(x)/\sqrt{x}}{1 + \sin(x)/\sqrt{x}}=\sin(x)/\sqrt{x}\left(1-\sin(x)/\sqrt{x}+O(1/x)\right)=\\\sin(x)/\sqrt{x}-\sin^2(x)/x+O(x^{-3/2})
$$
Now $\int_\pi^\infty \sin(x)/\sqrt{x}\; dx$ is convergent since  the series $\sum_n (-1)^n/\sqrt{n}  $ is convergent (alternating signs and terms tending to zero). In fact, write
$$
\int_{π}^{∞} \sin(x)/\sqrt{x}\; dx = \sum_n \int_{nπ}^{(n+1)\pi} \sin(x)/\sqrt{x}\; dx
$$
and you easily see that the integral and the series $\sum_n (-1)^n/\sqrt{n} $ are comparable.
Similarly, $\int_\pi^\infty \sin^2(x)/x\; dx$ is divergent since the series $\sum_n 1/n $ is divergent. For this, observe that:
$$
\int_{nπ}^{(n+1)\pi} \frac{\sin^2(x)}{x}\; dx\ge \int_{nπ}^{(n+1)\pi} \frac{\sin^2(x)}{(n+1)\pi}\; dx=\frac{1}{2 (n+1)}.
$$

Of course $\int_\pi^\infty O(x^{-3/2}) \; dx$ is convergent.

So you have two convergent contributions and a divergent one, hence the integral is divergent (and negative)

Answer (score 0):

you can see the integral as the sum integral between n^2pi and (n+1)^2pi the dominator in this interval is bigger than 1/((n+1)sq root of pi)+1) so the integral become the sum k*1/((n+1)sq root of pi)+1) where k is the integral of sin  between n^2pi.... and that series diverges 
I wish I can write with programation lg to be more helpful